# Backup and restore .sqlite database file of documents folder to iCloud?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, icloud

I want to store .sqlite database file in iCloud. I used this below code but when i login to my icloud account and see in " iCloud Drive " , there are no any file in that drive.

i only want the .sqlite file of my Apps Documents folder in icloud and restore from that backup.

I turn on iCloud option of Capabilities from xcode.[image]

Code :

```
NSString *dataFile = [self getDBPath];
        
_documentURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataFile];
       
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        
// [filemgr removeItemAtURL:_documentURL error:nil];
        
// _ubiquityURL = [[filemgr URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
        
_ubiquityURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
        
_ubiquityURL = [_ubiquityURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
        
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:[_ubiquityURL path]] == NO)
            [filemgr createDirectoryAtURL:_ubiquityURL
              withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                               attributes:nil
                                    error:nil];
        
_ubiquityURL = [_ubiquityURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"imageDB.sqlite"];
        
// Search for document in iCloud storage
_metadataQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];

[_metadataQuery setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE 'imageDB.sqlite'",NSMetadataItemFSNameKey]];
[_metadataQuery setSearchScopes:[NSArray
                                         arrayWithObjects:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope,nil]];
        
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(metadataQueryDidFinishGathering:) name: NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification object:_metadataQuery];

[_metadataQuery startQuery];
```

for upload database .sqlite file i used:

```
NSError *error = nil;
    
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:_documentURL destinationURL:_ubiquityURL error:&error] == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"setUbiquitous OK");
}
else
    NSLog(@"setUbiquitous Failed error = %@", error);
```

So please help me how can i backup my .sqlite whole file from my apps.

And also help me in download that file from cloud.

Comment: did you find a good example for this?

Comment: no @SAHM if you have then suggest me